# tricky binary subtraction

Tags: math, binary

So I was practicing my binary subtraction. It's been a long while since my first exam and I decided to create my own tricky binary subtraction and I came up with this one:

```
 1100
-1101
```

Of course the "borrowing trick" does not work for this problem at least I could not get it to work. Is my only choice to flip the bits of the second binary number(the bottom one) and then add a one basically doing 2's complement so 1101 becomes 0011. Then add the primary binary number(1100) with the 2's complement representation(0011) which means it would look like this:

```
    1100 (-4) assume 2's complement
+   0011 (3)  assume 2's complement

sum:1111 (-1) assume 2's complement
```

I just need confirmation on this problem since its been a long time since I did binary subtraction.

Comment: Yes - that looks correct for 4 bit 2s complement

Comment: Thanks Paul! A super fast feedback! Sweet! Props! =]

Comment: You may find more response on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I got a confirmation from Paul! Thanks Kryptonite for the link! I never knew about a math section! =]

Comment: Also try http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow so many wonderful resources! Thanks a bunch! =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 1100
-1101
```

`0 - 1 = 1` (borrow 1)

```
 1100
-1101
   1
=====
    1
```

`0 - 0 - 1 = 1` (borrow 1)

```
 1100
-1101
  11
=====
   11
```

`1 - 1 - 1 = 1` (borrow 1)

```
 1100
-1101
 111
=====
  111
```

`1 - 1 - 1 = 1` (borrow 1)

```
 1100
-1101
1111
=====
 1111
```

The result is `1111` with 1 borrowed. In terms of unsigned arithmetic, this means that either the result underflowed or you need to borrow from the next significant digit. (In terms of signed arithmetic there is no overflow as you have also borrowed the second bit and the calculation corresponds to `-4 - -3 = -1`.)